# "The function Create is not a member of "UnionOperation" when trying to use the TweenService()

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create a Maze Runner game. When making the doors to open and close i scripted it using ROBLOX's built in tween service. I run and i get "The function Create is not a member of "UnionOperation"" I have never heard of this error and couldn't find a solution. I am trying to do this on a Union part. I have no idea what to do. I need the tween to work as expected (tween the part a few spaces).

```
TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")
Door = script.Parent.Door2
Door1 = Door:WaitForChild("Door1")
Door2 = Door:WaitForChild("Door2")
local TweenInformationIn = TweenInfo.new(

    6,
    Enum.EasingStyle.Linear,
    Enum.EasingDirection.In,
    0,
    false,
    0
)

local Door1Open = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -769.185)}
local Door2Open = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -814.271)}
local Door1Close = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -749.831)}
local Door2Close = {CFrame = CFrame.new(1226.993, 131.187, -834.331)}
local Tween1Open = TweenService.Create(Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Open)
local Tween2Open =  TweenService.Create(Door2, TweenInformationIn,Door2Open)
local TweenClose =  TweenService.Create(Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Close)
local Tween2Close =  TweenService.Create(Door2,TweenInformationIn,Door2Close)

Tween1Open:Play()
Tween2Open:Play()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `TweenService.Create` with `TweenService:Create`

```
TweenService:Create(Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Open)
```

is equivalent to

```
TweenService.Create(TweenService, Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Open)
```

whereas you called

```
TweenService.Create(Door1, TweenInformationIn, Door1Open)
```

So inside `TweenService.Create` things went south because `Door1` was where `TweenService` should have been.

There is actually a code sample in the Robolox manual that shows how to use TweenService.

https://developer.roblox.com/api-reference/function/TweenService/Create

```
local TweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local part = Instance.new("Part")
part.Position = Vector3.new(0, 10, 0)
part.Anchored = true
part.Parent = game.Workspace

local tweenInfo = TweenInfo.new(
    2, -- Time
    Enum.EasingStyle.Linear, -- EasingStyle
    Enum.EasingDirection.Out, -- EasingDirection
    -1, -- RepeatCount (when less than zero the tween will loop indefinitely)
    true, -- Reverses (tween will reverse once reaching it's goal)
    0 -- DelayTime
)

local tween = TweenService:Create(part, tweenInfo, {Position = Vector3.new(0, 30, 0)})

tween:Play()
wait(10)
tween:Cancel() -- cancel the animation after 10 seconds
```